# How to configure auto update of view/form/dashboard on entity change via CRM SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Currently, we have the following situation:
`Account` entity contains `online_status` field, which can have either `offline` or `online` value. And we have an entity view, which shows only online accounts.

#### case1:

- I open the view. It's empty for now;
- I open an account form in another window and manually change online status from `offline` to `online`;
- After clicking `save`, grid in view auto updates and starts showing this account

#### case2:

I change online status using SDK:

```
using (var proxy = CreateCrmProxy(broker))
{
    proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
    var crmAccount = proxy.Retrieve(Account.EntityLogicalName, aggregateId, new ColumnSet()) as Account; 

    crmAccount.OnlineStatus = //new online status;
    proxy.Update(crmAccount);
}
```

`CreateCrmProxy` method creates an instance of `OrganizationServiceProxy` class.

In this case, `online_status` field updates successfully, but grid in view stays in an old state and I need to press "refresh" button in order to see valid information.

Is it possible to fire view auto update, using the technique from case2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cant do this with a plugin, since plugin is purely backend and sub-grids are a front-end UI construct.  Its possible you could do something hacky with calling a RetrieveMultiple after you make the update, but there wouldn't be any way to force the view to update itself.

A better option in your circumstance would be to trigger the change via javascript (a REST or SOAP Call would suffice), so that once the update is complete, then you can call a control.refresh.  It would get a bit trickier on a dashboard because you wouldn't have a form to load the javascript with and the view would be in a different pane, but you could do something with a web resource and use the parent context.

Comment: But when I update online status in CRM page, CRM subgrid is refreshed.

How does it happen? As far as I understood, some events in CRM are triggered, and subgrid is subscribed to those events. Or there is any other mechanism? Can't I use it?

Comment: The CRM "event" that occurs when you update a record on a crm page (from a sub-grid) is that a page side javascript function to reload the grid is called.  The reload grid does re-call the RetrieveMultiple Message.  There are crm server side events that you can register plugins against, but again - subgrids aren't hooked to these in the way you describe.  They make use of the RetrieveMultiple SDK action to get all relevant records, but theres no way to push this retrieve multiple action to a subgrid.